# Unable to read link from gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to populate hyperlink1 text on my webpage with the link from the selected gridview row. I am not able to get any value back. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        Me.NameTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(1).Text)
        Me.Product1DropDown.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(2).Text)
        Me.Product2DropDown.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(3).Text)
        Me.JobNumberTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(4).Text)
        Me.AdTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(5).Text)
        Me.MediaTypeDropDown.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(6).Text)
        Me.AuthorDropDown.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(7).Text)
        Me.PublicationDropDown.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(8).Text)
        Me.RunDatesTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(9).Text)
        Me.CostTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(10).Text)
        Me.CostCenterTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(11).Text)
        Me.CommentsTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(12).Text)
        Me.HyperLink1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(13).Text)
        Me.HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(13).Text)
        Me.TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(14).Text)
        Label14.Text = "Update"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: did you debug it? and check what is the value of Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(13).Text)

Comment: Yes, the value is nothing ""?

Comment: That is strange. does it mean row.Cells(13).Text is empty? what about other values?

Comment: All the other values a returned, I think it is because that column is a hyperlink column. I just debugged again and it is returning nothing.

Comment: Go it working thanks    Me.HyperLink1.Text = CType((row.Cells(13).Controls(0)), HyperLink).Text
            Me.HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = CType((row.Cells(13).Controls(0)), HyperLink).Text